# Mapping Windows Data Types to .NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, types

I have just been looking through the list of [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as I am trying to work out how each type maps to it's equivalent .NET type.

I noticed that some of the type definitions are surrounded by #if tags, which changes their definition based upon the platform.

For example, here is the definition for `INT_PTR`

```
#if defined(_WIN64) 
 typedef __int64 INT_PTR; 
#else 
 typedef int INT_PTR;
#endif
```

My understanding is that this creates a 64bit `INT_PTR` on 64bit machines, and a 32bit `INT_PTR` on 32bit machines. Okay....NET does the same thing in this respect as `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` are platform specific, and therefore adapt between 32bit and 64bit machines.

Now, lets consider `LONGLONG`

```
#if !defined(_M_IX86)
 typedef __int64 LONGLONG; 
#else
 typedef double LONGLONG;
#endif
```

So in .NET my assumption is that this maps to `Int64` (`long`) ?

Also, consider `TCHAR`

```
#ifdef UNICODE
 typedef WCHAR TCHAR;
#else
 typedef char TCHAR;
#endif
```

My assumption here is that this maps to char (since .NET's char is unicode anyway)?

**Questions:**

1. If a native type is platform dependent, should it's .NET equivalent be the larger of the two definitions?
2. Are there any known pitfalls when mapping data types?

Comment: What do you need this for? For native interop there is P/Invoke which can also marshal types on its own (e.g. you use `string` and it gets marshalled as a `wchar_t*`).

Comment: @Јοеу, as part of a bigger project, to create a utility where I can enter the C++ implementation (function/struct) into a textbox, and generate it's C# equivalent. I know such tools already exist, but they all seem to miss things out...especially with regards to _IN_, which should map to [In], but these seem to be omitted from many converters

Comment: `TCHAR` is a Windows 95 holdover, which you can safely ignore today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Platform Invoke Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120.aspx).

There are many pitfalls when mapping data types. For example, the difference between the Windows data types `BOOL` and `Boolean`. The default marshaling for the .NET `Boolean` data type (C# `bool`) will marshal it as a 32-bit integer to match the Windows `BOOL` type. The Windows `Boolean` data type is one byte. If you want to pass a C# `bool` to a Windows `Boolean`, you have to specify custom marshaling.

Structure packing can trip you up, and marshaling arrays can be very tricky, especially arrays inside structures.

You definitely want to read [Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae.aspx) very carefully.